# Inserting a content type column into a sharepoint library or document set

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, site-column

I have a document library with several documents within it. The documents are of various content types.

My question is i'd like to configure a view of the library where i can see which content type has been assigned to each document.

If i go into the library settings i can't see a column of content type which if assigned to show in the library view would allow me to understand which document has which content type.

Comment: If you head over to the view/create a new view, there should be a column called Content Type that you can add to your view/filter by or group by.

Comment: perfect! thanks ( although I really should have known that...)

Comment: Happens to me all the time. :)

Comment: How do i mark this question as answered?

Comment: You can't as i just added a comment.

Comment: @christoffer Please add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you head over to the view/create a new view in the list, there should be a column called `Content Type` that you can add to your view, filter by or even group by.